# Есть ли в javascript(nodejs) хеш-таблицы?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть ли в javascript (или хотя бы в node js), рекомендуемый тип данных, аналогичный хеш таблицам, для хранения уникальности строк большого размера?

То есть чтобы вычислялся хеш строки и сравнивался, и только если он совпадает дальше уже выполнялось бы сравнение строк напрямую.

Comment: Учитывая применяемое в разных языках (как минимум, в C# и Java) правило "у равных объектов хэш-коды должны совпадать", смысла в проверке строк после несовпадения хэш-кодов действительно не видно.

Comment: Перепутал. Если хеш код совпадает, то дальше уже следует сравнивать.

Comment: Есть Set https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: Да, хеш-таблица создается следующим образом: `hashTab = {};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, так и делается с ключами объекта. Используй `Object.create(null)`.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо.